# Sql join query and select one more column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables :  `answers`, `questions` and `users` and I have joined them all to get the result that I want

```
SELECT answers.answer_content as answer_content,
       answers.id as answer_id,
       answers.created_at as created_at,
       questions.id as question_id, 
       questions.question_title as question_title, 
       questions.question_slug as question_slug, 
       users.id as user_id, 
       users.name as user_name, 
       users.user_slug as user_slug,
                                  FROM answers
                                          JOIN questions
                                               on questions.id = answers.question_id
                                          JOIN users
                                               on users.id = answers.user_id
                                          WHERE questions.question_active = 1 and 
                                                answers.answer_active = 1
```

And Now I have one more table named `upvote_answers`. This table basically stores upvote, downvote for an answer by a user.

if a user has upvoted an answer i.e Columns are `user_id`, `answer_id`, `upvote` (1 or 0 - upvote or downvote respectively)

So my question is :
I want to get one more column with a boolean result that should show upvoted or downvoted or nothing for each answer for current logged in user

I tried writing the query like this

```
SELECT answers.answer_content as answer_content,
       answers.id as answer_id,
       answers.created_at as created_at,
       questions.id as question_id, 
       questions.question_title as question_title, 
       questions.question_slug as question_slug, 
       users.id as user_id, 
       users.name as user_name, 
       users.user_slug as user_slug,
       (SELECT count(upvote_answers.answer_id) from upvote_answers, answers WHERE upvote_answers.user_id = 2 and answers.id = upvote_answers.answer_id) as upvotedOrNot
                                  FROM answers
                                          JOIN questions
                                               on questions.id = answers.question_id
                                          JOIN users
                                               on users.id = answers.user_id
                                          WHERE questions.question_active = 1 and 
                                                answers.answer_active = 1
```

when User loggs in he should be able to see if he has upvoted or downvoted an answer or not.

Comment: didn't you ask this question already?

Comment: sorry, was told to write like this. posted again because could not make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that a given user can only vote once on any answer, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT answers.answer_content as answer_content,
       answers.id as answer_id,
       answers.created_at as created_at,
       questions.id as question_id, 
       questions.question_title as question_title, 
       questions.question_slug as question_slug, 
       users.id as user_id, 
       users.name as user_name, 
       users.user_slug as user_slug,
       upvote_answers.upvote as upvote
FROM 
    answers
    JOIN questions on questions.id = answers.question_id
    JOIN users on users.id = answers.user_id
    LEFT JOIN upvote_answers ON
        upvote_answers.answer_id = answers.id AND
        upvote_answers.user_id = answers.user_id
WHERE 
    questions.question_active = 1 and 
    answers.answer_active = 1
```

The `LEFT JOIN` clause will yield results if it matches, but will bring `NULL` values (for its table) if it does not.

Comment: Thanks, Let's say a user having an id of 5 who is logged in. where would i write that logic

Comment: showing null in every rows. even though user has upvoted

Comment: @user9452884 If without the `LEFT JOIN` works, adding `LEFT JOIN` will still give you values.

Comment: @user9452884 Are you sure that particular user answer that question, and actually has an upvote?